# Haproxy Layer 4 balancing with TLS

Tags: ssl, https, haproxy, tls

We have ssl3 turned off in favor of TLS. Most the tutorials on https for layer4 support with haproxy, ie ssl passthrough, uses check-ssl or ssl-hello-chk.

In our setup this will fail because we have ssl3 disabled.

My question is how to do passthrough with TLS so haproxy doesnt havent to terminate the cert but passes along to the web server for it handle. HTTP requests to the site works just fine, https does not. My current frontend/backend configuration goes as follows:

```
frontend layer4-listener
bind *:80  transparent
bind *:443 transparent
bind *:3306
mode tcp
option      tcplog
[...]


backend siteA
mode tcp
balance roundrobin
option tcpka
option tcp-check
server webserver_A www1.site.com:80 weight 1 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 3
server webserver_B www2.site.com:80 weight 1 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 3
```

Comment: Do you *need* `check-ssl`? Can you not just settle for a plain TCP SYN check?

Comment: I am sort of in the same boat as OP... In my case a TCP check isn't sufficient because the application server may be working, and the port could be open, but it may be overloaded.  In this case I would like a check to down the server from the candidate list.

Comment: which version of haproxy are you running?

Comment: im running 1.5.4